# error TS2562: Base class expressions cannot reference class type parameters

Tags: typescript

I have just updated the typescript for the software I'm working on from 2.4.1 to 2.6.2. I am tracking down any errors that have popped up due to this update and have come across this code:

```
export class WaitableFetcherComponent<T, U extends ReactNode> extends connection<T, U>().base() {
render() {
    return this.props.render(this.props.payload);
    }
}
```

The error appears in relation to the T and U types being sent to the `connection<T, U>()` function.
I am quiet new to typescript and have naively tried the following:

```
constructor() {
    super<T, U>();
}
```

To no avail.

Edit: Connection comes from here:

```
function connection<T, U extends ReactNode>() {
    return connectedComponent<WaitableFetcherProps<T, U>, {}>()
        .fetch(props => props.waitable, payload => ({ payload }));
}
```

How can I reference the class type parameters in the base class expression?

Comment: Where does `connection` come from ?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the code where the connection comes from.